# Editor wrap the text around at least once issue

Tags: xamarin, editor

xaml

```cs
<Editor x:Name="editor1" BackgroundColor="LightYellow" />
<Editor x:Name="editor2" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue" />
<Editor x:Name="editor3" BackgroundColor="LightYellow" />
```

cs

```cs
editor1.Text = "123";
editor2.Text = "1231231231231111111111111111111222222";
editor3.Text = "123\n123\n123456";
```

The result on the emulator (Android 9.0) is fine.

[image]

But on my phone (Android 9.0), there is one more whitespace line if each line of `Text` isn't long enough to be wrapped around no matter how many lines in `Text` such as `Text` of editor3.

[image]

I have tried to override the renderer, used `Control.SetMinHeight(1)`, `Control.SetMinLines(1)`, `Control.SetPadding(2, 1, 2, 1)`, didn't work.

How to let Editor wrap text around normally?

Comment: It works fine on my real device (Google Pixel). So which device did you test ? Try to deploy it on other device and check if the issue still appear .

Comment: It is obvious the DPI isn't the same on device vs the emulator you are using.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Meizu 16s. I have tried using Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0.1369, 4.8.0.1269, 4.8.0.1364. And I just tried on Huawei x9, it worked fine.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Shouldn't the application automatically adapt to the device? Or how can I solve it?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I think the difference of DPI still can't explain why `editor2` works fine.